# How to get SP expires on Date using Azure SDK for Golang?

Tags: azure, go

I have TenantID, SP Client Secret and SP Client ID.
I want to get the SP expire on Date, please refer attached screen shot.
I am using Azure SDK for Golang https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the link to the SDK you mentioned in your post.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong SDK. The SDK you would want to use for this is [`Microsoft Graph SDK for Go`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go).